# Core data: fetch from category (extension of core class)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

**EDIT**: For one I suppose I shouldn't make an instance method of this kind but make it a class method!? Another thing, I added the fetch method to class C, which works. I'm just thinking that it would be convenient if one could access the data store through the managed objects, but I suppose that somewhat goes against the ideas behind `managedObjectContext`,  persistence and so on?

---

I'm not sure if I'm trying to do something you're not supposed to do but here goes.

I have a data model with an entity A having a relationship to entity B (B to many A). I have a number of entities of type B in the data store, and now I would like to create a number of entities of type A. In order to do so I need to get references to the entities of type B, i.e., I have to query the data store. I do as follows in a B category, i.e.:

```
#import "B+Helper.h"

@dynamic managedObjectContext;

@implementation B (Helper)

- (Store *)getBByRef:(NSString *)ref
{
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ref == %@", ref];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *storeArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSInteger bCount = [bArray count];
    if ( bCount > 1 || bCount == 0) {
        // Deal with error...
    } else {
        return [bArray objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I cannot seem to set the managedObjectContext correctly---I get the error:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'B'
```

I tried passing the `managedObjectContext` from AppDelegate to the class C having to fetch the B entities and from class C to class B+Helper before calling the method stated above, but that didn't work.

Basically, I just want to be able to make a core date query from a simple `NSObject` class or a `NSManagedObject` extension, i.e., from a class which is not a `UIViewController` of some sort.

In class C I did as follows:

```
B *b = [[B alloc] init];
b.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

But then I get an error saying the selector is absent:

```
setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...
```

I hope it makes sense?!

Answer (score 0):

Really, instead of making a Category with instance method, you should just add your already written method to the  generated B entity class implementation and interface.

```
+ (Store *)getBByRef:(NSString *)ref;
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: Categories are actually really good to use with Core Data because if you have to regenerate your class files your methods won't get wiped out. Your idea is good though, it is just that I would put that class method in the category.

Comment: Right,from point of view of regenerating,Categories are great